# Trying to position div in horizontal layout

Tags: html, css

I would like to layout my website header with an image to the left and some text aligned at the bottom left ...

[image]

...or bottom right.

[image]

...or even better, have the image DIV height perfectly fit in the parent DIV :

[image]

...

Unfortunately I cannot get past this :

[image]

I am approaching this in two parts. The first part is to float my two inner elements left with a simple :

```
  float:left;
```

on both inner DIVs.

Then with the second inner DIV I am playing around with position

```
  position:fixed;
  right:0;
```

However if I also add **bottom:0** then I get something like this :

[image]

The second DIV has jumped ***outside*** of the outer DIV. How do I make it so that the positioning is relative to the parent DIV? I have tried position:inherit/absolute/fixed and nothing seems to work. Do I have to set something on the parent DIV?

Here is my JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/c0gjq2fb/8/

Is there something I am not understanding right? Is there a take home message? I never seem to understand HTML/CSS layouts no matter how hard I try :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Flexbox`

```css
.outer {
  border: 5px solid red;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: flex-start;
}
.inner2 {
  align-self: flex-end;
  border: 5px solid green;
}
img {
  border: 5px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <img src="http://www.frontangle.com/resources/FrontAngle_For_Site_PNG24.png">
  <div class="inner2">Some text</div>
</div>
```

Comment: is flexbox used in most browsers?

Answer (score 1):

The border is messed up cause of the `height: 100%;` value. If you remove the border, it's fine.

http://jsfiddle.net/j9p78a91/

Answer (score 1):

add

```
position:relative;
top:220px;
```

to css class .inner2.

```css
.outer {
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-color: red;
  width: 100%;
  height: 280px
}

.inner1 {
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-color: blue;
  float:left

}

.inner2 {
  border-color: green;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 5px;
  float:right;
  position:relative;
  right:0;
  top:220px;


}
```

```html
<div class="outer">

  <div class="inner1">
    <img src="http://www.frontangle.com/resources/FrontAngle_For_Site_PNG24.png">
  </div>

  <div class="inner2">
    Some text
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: the problem with this is that it is not responsive. If I make the width smaller then the green box does not cleanly jump under the image box. There is a huge gap between the two.